# How to add a value based on another field's value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm new to Data Factory. I'm trying to copy the data from a source to Dataverse. So far I have a basic demo that allows me to read data from the source, perform a simple lookup, set the guid and add a static value by using "additional columns" in the source options and copy all of that to my Dataverse table.

However I have a couple of fields in my source data that don't match what I need for Dataverse. E.g. I have a column with 1 or 0 as a value that requires true/false in Dataverse. So I need to something like an "if else" where for every row I can check the value of a field and create a new value based on that that I can later use for lookups and/or copying the data to Dataverse.

I've been looking at the Docs but its a bit unclear to me how I should go about this. How can I best check the value of a field and create a new field with the value I need based on the existing value?

Comment: You do have few options directly in the `CopyActivity` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79kAs.png) but this is the other way around considering your scenario.  (Treat Boolean as number i.e. converting from true/false to 1/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Data flows in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) is the thing for you.

You can use transformations like [Derived column transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to generate new columns or modify existing fields. Here you can update columns by identifying their data using patterns, conditions and expressions to set new values.

### Example:

Using expression as below to identify a column with 1 or 0 and set required value true/false.

```
iif(condition, true_expression, false_expression)
```

Working example for a column:

```
iif(toInteger(column_name) == 1,'true', 'false')
```

[image]

verify the transformation using data preview

[image]

Refer to learn more: [Data transformation expressions in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions)

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now. I also found out you can use 'case' do simulate something like if else if.